# How to Download JSON Data Files Using API from Census Bureau

Tags: r, json, api

I'm trying to use R to download the International Trade data from the Census Bureau. They provide an API which returns JSON data like the following example. I'm not familiar with APIs and JSON. How can I query the API through R?

```
{
      "@context": "https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema/catalog.jsonld",
      "@id": "https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/eits/ftd.json",
      "@type": "dcat:Catalog",
      "conformsTo": "https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema",
      "describedBy": "https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema/catalog.json",
      "dataset": [
            {
                  "c_dataset": [
                        "timeseries",
                        "eits",
                        "ftd"
                        ],
                  "c_geographyLink": "https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/eits/ftd/geography.json",
                  "c_variablesLink": "https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/eits/ftd/variables.json",
                  "c_examplesLink": "https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/eits/ftd/examples.json",
                  "c_groupsLink": "https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/eits/ftd/groups.json",
                  "c_valuesLink": "https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/eits/ftd/values.json",
                  "c_documentationLink": "http://www.census.gov/developer/",
                  "c_isTimeseries": true,
                  "c_isCube": true,
                  "c_isAvailable": true,
                  "@type": "dcat:Dataset",
                  "title": "Time Series Economic Indicators Time Series -: U.S. International Trade in Goods and Services",
                  "accessLevel": "public",
                  "bureauCode": [
                        "006:07"
                        ],
                  "description": "The U.S. Census Bureau.s economic indicator surveys provide monthly and quarterly data that are timely, reliable, and offer comprehensive measures of the U.S. economy. These surveys produce a variety of statistics covering construction, housing, international trade, retail trade, wholesale trade, services and manufacturing. The survey data provide measures of economic activity that allow analysis of economic performance and inform business investment and policy decisions. Other data included, which are not considered principal economic indicators, are the Quarterly Summary of State & Local Taxes, Quarterly Survey of Public Pensions, and the Manufactured Homes Survey.  For information on the reliability and use of the data, including important notes on estimation and sampling variance, seasonal adjustment, measures of sampling variability, and other information pertinent to the economic indicators, visit the individual programs' webpages - http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/briefroom/BriefRm.",
                  "distribution": [
                        {
                              "@type": "dcat:Distribution",
                              "accessURL": "https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/eits/ftd",
                              "description": "API endpoint",
                              "format": "API",
                              "mediaType": "application/json",
                              "title": "API endpoint"
                        }
                        ],
                  "contactPoint": {
                        "fn": "Economic Indicators Mail List",
                        "hasEmail": "econ.indicators@census.gov"
                  },
                  "identifier": "http://api.census.gov/data/id/EITSFTD",
                  "keyword": [
                        ],
                  "license": "http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/Public Domain",
                  "modified": "2017-02-23",
                  "programCode": [
                        "006:007"
                        ],
                  "references": [
                        "http://www.census.gov/developers/"
                        ],
                  "spatial": "United States",
                  "temporal": "January 1992 - Current",
                  "publisher": {
                        "@type": "org:Organization",
                        "name": "U.S. Census Bureau",
                        "subOrganizationOf": {
                              "@type": "org:Organization",
                              "name": "U.S. Department Of Commerce",
                              "subOrganizationOf": {
                                    "@type": "org:Organization",
                                    "name": "U.S. Government"
                              }
                        }
                  }
            }
            ]
}
```

More details: the API's can be found here: https://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/international-trade.html

the data can be manually downloaded from here with log-in required: https://usatrade.census.gov/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be, to send a `GET` request to the API by using `httr::GET()`. The URL below is taken from their examples. You can modify the URL parameters (e.g. change `year=2013` to `year=2000`) to retrieve different results. Lastly, I use `data.table::rbindlist()` to bind the nested list into a `data.table/data.frame` object.

```
require(httr)
require(data.table)

url = "https://api.census.gov/data/timeseries/intltrade/exports/hs?get=DISTRICT,DIST_NAME,E_COMMODITY,E_COMMODITY_LDESC,ALL_VAL_MO,ALL_VAL_YR,VES_VAL_MO,VES_VAL_YR&YEAR=2013&MONTH=12&DISTRICT=13"

res = GET(url)
cont = content(res) # parses the API result (recognizes JSON)

dat = rbindlist(cont)
```

You can have a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/api-packages.html), for how to work with APIs in R.

Comment: Thanks so much! The article is very helpful. Still don't understand some of it, but I'm getting to know API and how it works a little better now. Really appreciate it!

Comment: How did you learn how to set `DISTRICT`?